# What are the keyboard controls for NFS most wanted 2012?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I have NFS most wanted 2012 for my PC, and I want to know all the keyboard controls.

Also, are there many different tracks/scenerios because I find the interface very confusing and don't understand how I can switch to different scenes/tracks.

Comment: ...Is there not a controls page in the game itself?

Answer (score 2):

> > <kbd>Esc</kbd> > setting > control > keyboard

To switch, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> button.